# How to have consistent margin/padding against a span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have some text in `p` tags and I wish to have them consistently aligned again their respective span texts.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

But I want the text on the right side to be consistently aligned with the left side.
This is what I want:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div className="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span className="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_ACCELERATE
  </span>
  <p className="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0.4, 0, 1, 1)
  </p>
</div>

<div className="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span className="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_DECELERATE
  </span>
  <p className="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0, 0, 0.2, 1)
  </p>
</div>

<div className="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span className="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_STANDARD
  </span>
  <p className="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
  </p>
</div>

<div className="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span class="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_SHARP
  </span>
  <p className="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0.4, 0, 0.6, 1)
  </p>
</div>
```

And this is my styling:

```
.basic-flex-large-gap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.gray-dynamic {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F6F8FA;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'NMyFont', Sans-serif;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #212121;
}
.span-text {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'MyFont', Sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.
Any and all help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you are grouping them in divs row wise vs column wise?

Comment: It's because I want each of the rows to be aligned together. So the TRANSITION and it's respective cubic bezier should be aligned together. It's the reason why I have the basic-flex-large-group css rules.

Comment: Why don't you try putting them in a table?

Comment: I think a table may be better. But would I also be able to ensure the TRANSITION and it's respective cubic bezier be aligned together?

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Tables (or an actual `table`) is your best option

```css
.basic-flex-large-gap {
  display: table-row;
}

.gray-dynamic {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'NMyFont', Sans-serif;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #212121;
}

.span-text {
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'MyFont', Sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span class="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_ACCELERATE
  </span>
  <p class="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0.4, 0, 1, 1)
  </p>
</div>

<div class="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span class="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_DECELERATE
  </span>
  <p class="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0, 0, 0.2, 1)
  </p>
</div>

<div class="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span class="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_STANDARD
  </span>
  <p class="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
  </p>
</div>

<div class="basic-flex-large-gap">
  <span class="gray-dynamic">
    TRANSITION_SHARP
  </span>
  <p class="span-text">
    cubic-bezier (0.4, 0, 0.6, 1)
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up using a table, thank you so much.